# Validate 2dp decimal value with regex

Tags: jquery, regex

My code works so far but I can't enter any numbers when BOTH decimals are set.
Any idea whats wrong?

```js
$("input").keypress(function(e) {
  var el = $(this);
  var key = e.keyCode || e.which;
  key = String.fromCharCode(key);
  var value = el.val() + key;
  var regex = /^\d+(,\d{0,2})?$/;
  if (!regex.test(value)) {
    e.returnValue = false;
    if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="1234,56">
```

Comment: Your description of the problem isn't clear. What do you mean by 'I can't enter any numbers when BOTH decimals are set'? I can't find a way to break this, given your regex

Comment: Try entering digits, it won't work .. when removing either one or both decimals it will work.

Comment: It's working fine for me in Chrome 71. I changed the value to `9999,99`, amongst others.

Comment: Your method is appending the key to the val in the box and then validating.  If you are overwriting a number in the value, you aren't properly validating what is being inputted

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allow only 2 decimal points entry to a textbox using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17083965/allow-only-2-decimal-points-entry-to-a-textbox-using-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will also reject backspace, delete and arrow keypresses, which will make it near impossible for the user to correct a number that is already there.

I would suggest not responding to `keypress`, but to the `input` event, because it also triggers when changes are made via the mouse (drag in a text), the context menu (clear, paste) or other input devices.

The difference is that `input` triggers after the change has been made, but this is not so bad. You can just remove the part of the input that does not fit with the regular expression:

```js
$("input").on('input', function(e){
    var clean = $(this).val().replace(/^(\d+(,\d{0,2})?)?.*/g, "$1");
    $(this).val(clean);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="1234,56">
```

The above solution removes the rest of the input that follows after a character that violates the pattern. In case you want to keep as many input characters as possible, you could perform a loop in which you only delete one violating character at a time:

```js
$("input").on('input', function(e){
    var clean = $(this).val(), input;
    while (input != clean) {
        input = clean;
        clean = input.replace(/^(\d+(,\d{0,2})?)?.?/g, "$1");
    }
    $(this).val(clean);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="1234,56">
```

Comment: it's almost perfect :) but try moving to the beginning of the textbox, then enter comma, the textbox will be blank .. it requires extra validation but i think i'll figure that out.

Comment: That is because the regex demands that the input cannot start with a comma. This solution removes both the invalid character and anything that follows it.

Comment: I added a second solution that retains as many characters as possible after something invalid was inserted.